# Why does this very simple and little C++ program terminates with -1073741819 (0xC0000005)?

Tags: c++, destructor, terminate

I have a simple class with a destructor. If I instantiate an object from it with default constructor, then the program terminates succesfully, but if I instantiate it with a constructor that has any parameter, it terminates unsuccesfully.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <list>

class MyClass {
public:
    std::list<int>* myList;
    MyClass();
    MyClass(int a);
    ~MyClass();
};

MyClass::MyClass() {}
MyClass::MyClass(int a) {}
MyClass::~MyClass() { delete myList; }

int main()
{

    // If I do only this, the program terminates succesfully with 0 as return value
    MyClass graph1();

    // But if I do this, the program terminates unsuccesfully
    MyClass graph2(3);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Why is `myList` a pointer to a std::list? This is unusual and also the cause of your problem.

Comment: `delete myList` - but you never `new` it !

Comment: If you want to go about having `myList` as a pointer your class must also follow the rule of 3 or 5 which is a more work than the rule of 0. [https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/rule_of_three](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/rule_of_three)

Comment: since C++11 do not use `new` and `delete` explicitly. Take advantage of RAII pattern and use `std::unique_ptr` and `std::shared_ptr`. Also having a pointer to a `srd::list<int>` is a bit an overkill.

Comment: This is UB (`delete`ing a pointer you never `new`) and the code is allowed to do anything, but I am surprised by that specific behavior.

Comment: My advice is change `std::list<int>* myList;` to `std::list<int> myList;` and get rid of `delete myList;` and the code for the destructor.

Comment: The destructor of your class does `delete myList` but `myList` is an uninitialised pointer since the constructors have not initialised it.   The behaviour is therefore undefined.   The behaviour you are seeing is one of many possible symptoms of that.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`MyClass graph1();` doesn't create an instance of `MyClass`, whether initialized with the default constructor or otherwise. Rather, it's a declaration of a function taking no parameters and returning `MyClass`. See also: [most vexing parse](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Most_vexing_parse)

`MyClass graph2(3);` does create an instance of `MyClass`. Its constructor leaves `myList` pointer uninitialized, and then its destructor exhibits undefined behavior by way of accessing said uninitialized pointer.

Comment: Ahhhh, that makes sense.  The most vexing parse is appropriately named.

Comment: @DanielH — appropriately named, but not appropriately invoked. This is not an example of the most vexing parse. It is simply a function declaration.